# Saving picture from URL to an object in Cloud Code

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm using Cloud Code in order to save an image from a URL. When the image has been taken, i create a new object and pass the data to it and then save the object. Here is what i'm doing:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("saveImage", function(request, response){
var urlString = request.params.url;
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ url : urlString}).then(function(response2){
    var PictureObject = Parse.Object.extend("pictures");
    var pictureObject = new PictureObject();

    pictureObject.set("photo", response2.buffer);//problem might be here
    pictureObject.save(null, {
        success: function(pictureObject){
            response.success ("object created");
        }, error: function(){
            response.error("Error");
        }
    });
});
```

});

When i run the code i get an error response which means the object wasn't saved. I commented out the line where i save the response buffer to "photo" and replaced it with another setter where i only save text to a property. When i run the code, the object get's saved. Thus the problems seems to be in the the setter of the buffer. I'm new to javascript that's why i'm confused and can't find a solution. any hint will be really appreciated.

Note: reponse2 is returning the data of the picture so it's not nil.

Comment: Are you trying to save the url? Or the actual file? If you're saving the file, create a Parse File and then you can store the url of that in your pictures class.